# Sinon stub functions that are exported through an index file

Tags: typescript, sinon

Consider the following typescript files:

- A.ts

```
export const funcA = ()=>{}
```

- B.ts

```
export const funcB = ()=>{}
```

- index.ts

```
export * from './A.ts'
export * from './B.ts'
```

Now in my tests, if I import the inner file directly, I am able to mock its members:

```
import * as A from './A.ts'
sinon.stub(A,'funcA');
```

However, if I import the index, it won't let me mock its members:

```
import * as myModule from `./index.ts`
sinon.stub(myModule,'funcA'); // does not work
```

Can someone explain? Is there a different approach?

Comment: Also ran into this. Did you ever find a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is what works for me,

in the index.ts file, instead of doing like this

```
export * from './A.ts'
export * from './B.ts'
```

I ended up using the default

```
import { funcA } from './A.ts';
import { funcB } from './B.ts';

export default {funcA, funcB};
```

then on my test file, I could stub like

```
import myModule from `./index.ts`
sinon.stub(myModule,'funcA'); // now works
```